# Can it be the case that changing which table a GROUP BY expression takes its value from changes the resulting groups?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite 3.41.2.

I have a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT Table1.Name AS Table1Name
       Table2.Name AS Table2Name
       MAX(Value) AS Value
FROM Table1
JOIN RelationTable USING (ID1)
JOIN Table2 USING (ID2)
WHERE Value = <subquery>
GROUP BY Table2.ID2;
```

Is it possible that the behaviour of the `GROUP BY` clause depends on whether it is `Table2.ID2` or `RelationTable.ID2`? It seems to me that this should not change the behaviour, but this is exactly what is happening with my query. Is it possible the the subquery (which I have elided here) is somehow *clobbering* or *shadowing* these identifiers (as I query `RelationTable` again in the subquery)?

If you must know, I would be willing to provide the full query and the database schema. It is, however, an exercise database and it is in German, so the semantic content may not be clear. In light of this let me state that I do not believe this issue is necessarily relevant to the exercise I am doing, so I am not asking for help on the exercise.

Comment: It's not clear without a minimally reproducible example, but since you're using bare columns, it's at least theoretically possible the results will be different. For each `id` it has to take `Table1.Name` and `Table2.Name` from a row that has a `value` equal to the `MAX(VALUE)`, but it is arbitrary in the case of ties. It seems plausible that changing the `group by` is changing the order it grabs things and ultimately picking a different arbitrary row that still follows the rules. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query

Comment: That is possibly the cause, thank you. I would like to mark this as accepted, but I cannot since it is not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer:

It's not clear without a minimally reproducible example, but since you're using bare columns, it's at least theoretically possible the results will be different. For each id it has to take `Table1.Name` and `Table2.Name` from a row that has a value equal to the `MAX(VALUE)`, but it is arbitrary in the case of ties.

It seems plausible that changing the `group by` is changing the order the query grabs things and ultimately picking a different arbitrary row that still follows the rules.

You can read more about [the rules for bare columns here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) (note the special case for `min`/`max`).